# Laravel 5.2 validator: Validate Array request parameter, at least one value must be selected

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am having a form where i am having title, body, answers[*][answer] and options[*][option].

I want atleast one answer must be selected for the given question,  for example:

i have `ABC` question and having 5 options for that question,now atleast one answer must be checked or all for given question.

**Efforts**

```
protected $rules = [
            'title' => 'required|unique:contents|max:255',
            'body' => 'required|min:10',
            'type' => 'required',
            'belongsto' => 'sometimes|required',
            'options.*.option' => 'required|max:100',
            'answers.*.answer' => 'required',
        ];
```

But this is not working. i want atleast one answer must be selected.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on $_POST an array filled with empty strings will be passed if no answer is selected.

```
$answers[0][0] = ''
$answers[0][1] = ''
$answers[0][2] = ''
```

Hence the following will not work since array count will be greater than zero due to the empty strings:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'answers.*'   => 'required'
  ]);
```

The easiest way to solve this is to create a custom Validator rule by using Laravel's Validator::extend function.

```
  Validator::extendImplicit('arrayRequireMin', function($attribute, $values, $parameters)
  {
      $countFilled = count(array_filter($values));
      return ($countFilled >= $parameters[0]);
  });
```

And then call it in your Validation request:

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'answers.*'   => 'arrayRequireMin:1'
  ]);
```

The magic happens in array_filter() which removes all empty attributes from the array. Now you can set any minimum number of answers required.

Validator::extendImplicit() vs Validator::extend()

> For a rule to run even when an attribute is empty, the rule must imply that the attribute is required. To create such an "implicit" extension, use the Validator::extendImplicit() method:

[Laravel's validation docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    'answer.0' => 'required'
```

it will help you. I think.